# Exchange operator with position and momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, notation

I need to prove that for a  given exchange operator $\hat{P}_{12}$ such that,
$$\hat{P}_{12}|x_1,x_2\rangle = |x_2,x_1\rangle $$

$\hat{P}_{12}\hat{X}_1\hat{P}_{12}=x_2$ and $\hat{P}_{12}\hat {P}_1\hat{P}_{12}=p_2$ where $\hat{X}_i$ is the position and $\hat{P}_i$ is the momentum operator. It looks so simple but I could not figure it out how to approach the problem...Any ideas

Note: It seems that my mistake was seeing $x_i$ is just as a position and not as an operator...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll change the notation a bit to make everything clearer. In fact, the problem *is* very easy, once we have introduced a proper notation. In the following, we omit the discussion of some possible mathematical problems, i.e. the following is not completely rigorous.

Let $H$ and $\mathscr H=H\otimes H $ denote some Hilbert spaces. For $u,v\in H$ and thus $u\otimes v\in\mathscr H$, we define the exchange operator as
$$  \mathrm{Ex}\, u\otimes v := v\otimes u \quad .\tag{1}$$

Now consider an operator $A$ on $H$; we can "lift" this operator to $\mathscr H$ by defining $A_1 := A\otimes \mathbb I$ and $A_2 := \mathbb I\otimes A$, where $\mathbb I$ denotes the identity operator on $H$. These expression mean that
\begin{align}
 A_1 \,u\otimes v &:= Au\otimes v \quad \tag{2a}\\
 A_2 \,u\otimes v &:= u\otimes Av \quad \tag{2b} \quad .
\end{align}

The desired equality now trivially follows by examining the action of $\mathrm{Ex}\,A_1 \mathrm{Ex}$ and $A_2$ on $u\otimes v$ and showing that both agree for all $u,v\in H$:
$$ \mathrm{Ex}\,A_1\mathrm{Ex}\, u\otimes v\overset{(1)}{=}\mathrm{Ex}\,A_1\, v\otimes u \overset{(2\mathrm a)}{=} \mathrm{Ex}\, Av\otimes u \overset{(1)}{=} u\otimes Av \overset{(2\mathrm b)}{=} A_2 \, u\otimes v \quad ,\tag{3}$$

which, since this holds for all $u\otimes v \in \mathscr H$ and hence for all vectors in $\mathscr H$, as an equality of operators means $\mathrm{Ex}\,A_1\mathrm{Ex} = A_2$. Moreover, as $\mathrm{Ex}^2 = \mathbb I\otimes \mathbb I$, we immediately obtain $\mathrm{Ex}\,A_2\mathrm{Ex} = A_1$.

As a final note, let us stress that for all of this to make sense we needed that $\mathscr H = H\otimes H$ and not e.g. $\mathscr H = H_1 \otimes H_2$ with $H_1$ different from $H_2$.

Edit: To translate it in the notation used in the question, simply substitute $u\otimes v$ with e.g. $|x_1,x_2\rangle$ and $A_i$ with e.g. $X_i$ and, well, $\mathrm{Ex}$ with $P_{12}$.

Comment: This seems good but too advanced for my level...

Comment: @seVenVo1d Can you explain why? I can then try to elaborate.

Comment: @seVenVo1d I've added a small explanation how to translate the expressions. The upshot is that I think that this cannot be too advanced for you, as *everything* I am describing here is implicitly understood in the notation you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now with a focused mind it seems more clear.

Comment: @seVenVo1d No problem. If you still have questions regarding this, let me know. But to be honest, I think that the bra-ket notation here is more confusing than helpful (as so often). Thus, I really understand your confusion.

Answer (score 7):

Let us suppose that the vectors $|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle$ form a basis of your Hilbert space and that ${\cal O}_1$ and ${\cal O}_2$ are operators such that $${\cal O}_1|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle=\alpha_1|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle,\quad {\cal O}_2|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle=\alpha_2|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle.$$

You want to evaluate $P_{12}{\cal O}_iP_{12}$. Since an operator is defined by its action on a basis, we apply this to the basis. First use the definition of $P_{12}$.

$$P_{12}{\cal O}_iP_{12}|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle= P_{12} {\cal O}_i |\alpha_2,\alpha_1\rangle$$

Now notice that ${\cal O}_1|\alpha_2,\alpha_1\rangle=\alpha_2$ and ${\cal O}_2|\alpha_2,\alpha_1\rangle=\alpha_1|\alpha_2,\alpha_1\rangle$. For that reason we have $$P_{12}{\cal O}_1P_{12}|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle= \alpha_2P_{12}|\alpha_2,\alpha_1\rangle=\alpha_2|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle={\cal O}_2|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle,$$

and likewise $$P_{12}{\cal O}_2P_{12}|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle=\alpha_1P_{12}|\alpha_2,\alpha_1\rangle=\alpha_1|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle={\cal O}_1|\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle.$$

We therefore observe that $P_{12}{\cal O}_1P_{12}={\cal O}_2$ and $P_{12}{\cal O}_2P_{12}={\cal O}_1$ because the operators in the LHS and the operators on the RHS agree when acting on a basis.

Now you can apply this result with ${\cal O}_i = X_i$ or with ${\cal O}_i=P_i$ or any other operators you want.

Comment: What about the $\hat{P_i}$ can we just say $\hat{P_i}|x_1,x_2> = p_1|x_1,x_2>$

Comment: @seVenVo1d No. But you can use a different basis, e.g. the tensor product of elements of the eigenbasis of the momentum operator,  i.e. something like $|p_1,p_2\rangle$. But you don't have to use any eigenbasis at all.

Comment: @seVenVo1d I have updated the answer to be more general. I had written with position operator in mind but this works for any operators. The only thing is that in the proof you would then use the basis of eigenvectors of the operator.